# Apply a pattern against a calendar

Tags: php, date, iteration

Say I have a pattern of letters that simply repeats itself forever - is there an easy way to apply this pattern to a calendar?

For example, the actual pattern itself is `E1, E, E, E, O, O, N1, N1, N, O, O, O, L, L1, L1, L, O, O, E, E, E1, O, O, N, N, N, N, O, O, O, L, L, L, O, O, E1, E, E, E, O, O`

I would like to then take this pattern and apply it for the rest of the year (and if possible, a year or two after that aswell) starting from a given date, in my case, the 25th February 2012.

I've been thinking about how to solve this using PHP without having to resort to doing it manually but I can't think of the steps to take, all I can think is that it will make extensive use of the `date()` function!

All joking aside, I think putting these values into an array might be a good first step and use that structure as the basis of the loop?

Ideal output would simply be:

`dd/mm/yyyy : one of E1/E/O/N1/N`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this was deleted, it was almost correct. All I added is the while loop from the previous answer. All credit to original poster.

```
<?php
$str = "E1, E, E, E, O, O, N1, N1, N, O, O, O, L, L1, L1, L, O, O, E, E, E1, O, O, N, N, N, N, O, O, O, L, L, L, O, O";
$now = strtotime('25th Feb 2012'); // Now in unix-timestamp (seconds since epoch)
$end = strtotime('2013-02-25');
while ($now <= $end)
{
    foreach (explode(', ', $str) as $val) { // Loop through each value
        print date("d/m/Y", $now) . " : {$val}<br />\n"; // Format output
        $now += 86400; // Add 1 day to $now (86400 seconds)
        if ($now >= $end) break; // Close after $end date
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you, this answer was the closest to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In php it's very easy using a `Julian Date`n

```
$str = explode(', ',"E1, E, E, E, O, O, N1, N1, N, O, O, O, L, L1, L1, L, O, O, E, E, E1, O, O, N, N, N, N, O, O, O, L, L, L, O, O");
$now = GregorianToJD(date('m'),date('j'),date('Y'));
$start = GregorianToJD(1,13,1993); // Start January 13th 1993
$days = $now-$start; //get total days
$tod = $str[($days % count($str)) - 1]; //Total days mod amount of options -1 gets you the key to the currect code.
echo "today is $tod";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like this:

```
<?php
    function valueFor($check_date){
        //the data reference
        $data = "E1, E, E, E, O, O, N1, N1, N, O, O, O, L, L1, L1, L, O, O, E, E, E1, O, O, N, N, N, N, O, O, O, L, L, L, O, O";
        $data_ary = explode(',',str_replace(' ','',$data));
        $start_stamp = strtotime("2012-02-25");
        $check_stamp = strtotime($check_date);
        //get difference of days for both dates
        $days_diff = floor( ($check_stamp - $start_stamp) / (60*60*24) );
        if($days_diff > count($data_ary)) $days_diff = ( $days_diff % count($data_ary) ) - 1;
        return $data_ary[$days_diff];
    }

    //=> this will output 'E1'
    echo valueFor('2012-04-01'); 
?>
```

So you simply call the function passing the date.